# uninitialized constant V1 Only on Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide, versionist

I just moved my Rails app which uses the versionist gem to www.c9.io. When doing rails s on my local machine I have no problem browsing, however when I try to view it on c9 I get `uninitialized constant V1`. I'm not sure where to start as to what to provide you with to help me.

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    api_version(
        :module => "V1",
        :header => {
        :name => "Accept",
        :value => "application/vnd.ContractTracker; version=1"},
        :default => true) do

      resources :contracts, defaults: {format: :json}

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being because the path to the controller in question was `app/controllers/V1/foo_controller.rb`. Once I changed it to `app/controllers/v1/foo_controller.rb` everything worked fine. Notice the change was `V1` to `v1` (capital V). I think the fix is how it should have been setup to begin with, I'm not 100% sure why OSX was allowing it to function in this case.